# Spllit string and assign to two columns using Pandas assign method

Tags: python, pandas

If using the following DataFrame I can split the "ccy" string and create two new columns:

```
df_so = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0: 'gbp_usd',
 1: 'eur_usd',
 2: 'usd_cad',
 3: 'usd_jpy',
 4: 'eur_usd',
 5: 'eur_usd'},orient='index',columns=["ccy"])

df_so[['base_ccy', 'quote_ccy']] = df_so['ccy'].str.split('_', 1, expand=True)
```

giving the following DataFrame.

| index | ccy | base_ccy | quote_ccy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | gbp_usd | gbp | usd |
| 1 | eur_usd | eur | usd |
| 2 | usd_cad | usd | cad |
| 3 | usd_jpy | usd | jpy |
| 4 | eur_usd | eur | usd |
| 5 | eur_usd | eur | usd |

How do I do the same `str.split` using [DataFrame.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) within my tweak function below
?

I can do this with a list comprehension to get the same result, but is there a simpler/cleaner way using assign?:

```
def tweak_df (df_):
  return (df_.assign(base_currency= lambda df_: [i[0] for i in df_['ccy'].str.split('_', 1)],
                     quote_currency= lambda df_: [i[1] for i in df_['ccy'].str.split('_', 1)],
                     )        
  )
tweak_df(df_so)
```

Yields same result as the table above but the code is not very intuitive and simple is better than complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think the first version you suggested is the best.

```
df_so[['base_ccy', 'quote_ccy']] = df_so['ccy'].str.split('_', 1, expand=True)
```

If you want to do it using assign, you can do it like this utilising the rename function.

```
df_so.assign(**df_so['ccy'].str.split('_', n=1, expand=True)
             .rename(columns={0: "base_ccy", 1: "quote_ccy"}))
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
df_so.assign(**tweak_df(df_so))
```

Output:

```
       ccy base_ccy quote_ccy base_currency quote_currency
0  gbp_usd      gbp       usd           gbp            usd
1  eur_usd      eur       usd           eur            usd
2  usd_cad      usd       cad           usd            cad
3  usd_jpy      usd       jpy           usd            jpy
4  eur_usd      eur       usd           eur            usd
5  eur_usd      eur       usd           eur            usd
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code pls?

Comment: I guess that is not necessary anymore, since someone else has offered you a solution, which you have accepted, @nipy. Best wishes!